# How to display jenkins default environment variable from shell command?

Tags: shell, jenkins, environment-variables

I am not able to get output of the **Environment-Variable** `BUILD_URL` through Shell command.

> Configured **Manage Jenkins-->Configure System-->Jenkins Location-->Jenkins URL** as `http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/`

Using below script within Shell command.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo ${BUILD_URL}
```

Do i have to set jenkins_url within the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a Shell you can't access environment variables like that. you will need to read here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-read-and-set-environmental-and-shell-variables-on-a-linux-vps.

What you can do is in the Jenkins's job session you can send a parameter to your script to gain access to the env parameter. in the Shell section you will have access to the environment parameter, in the script itself it'll work differently.

Good luck

Comment: I know this variable. I'm saying that if you want to access it from a Shell script you will need to either use "printenv BUILD_URL" or you will need to send ${BUILD_URL} to your script when you run it.

Comment: If it helped you - can you please mark it as the right answer? :)